# Regarding Maintenance mode in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am working on ASP.NET Core web app with MVC6. I want to implement maintenance mode in my web app such that only certain type of users are allowed to login to web app when it is under maintenance mode. For example all user EXCEPT user with role `user` are allowed to login. To achieve this functionality I tried following code.

```
//Sign in user with provided username and password
var res = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(suser.UserName, user.Password, user.Remember, false);
if (res.Succeeded)
{
      //check if web app is under maintenance mode and if it is, then check the role of the user
      if (_env.IsEnvironment("Maintenance") && await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(suser, "user"))
           return View("Maintenance"); //if user is in 'user' role redirect to maintenance view
      else
      {
          //else redirect to main page
      }
}
```

The above code is executed when specific user tries to login to web app. The problem with above code is that it won't work when user is already logged in and tries to access the web app. in that case it will be redirected to the main page of web app regardless of maintenance mode. How do Logout already logged in user when they tried to access web app under maintenance mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an action filter or a middle ware that executes the same check for every request

To read more about filters, check this link https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/filters.html

Comment: How do I use `SignInManager` in custom filter?

Comment: You don't need the `SignInManager`, only the `UserManager` is what you need to check if the user is in role or not, and you can get it from the current `OwinContext`, if you are using the default VS template, it normally register an instance of `UserManager` in the `OwinContext` and you can retrieve it using the following code: 
`using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity; 
var manager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserManager<User>>();`

Comment: What i would like to do in custom filter is that first check if website is in maintenance mode or not(done using environment variable). then check if user is already logged in or not. If user is logged in and website is under maintenance mode, then sign out the user and redirect user to login page. After user is logged out and if user will try to log in to website again in maintenance mode then the code that I mention above will handle the rest.

Comment: The code you wrote above only handle the case when the user tries to log in, but after the login, the user can simply navigate to the other pages and he will be able to do that, so you need a code that runs for every request which is the filter. 
What you have mentioned in your comment can be done using simple if statement